# what is the problem with declaring a variable bounded by a parameter in the function itself rather than in the main function?

Tags: c++, function, input, declare

I have been trying to include the declaration of the variable in the function itself but it doesn't work unless I include it in the main function. Why does this happen?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



function1(int x)
{
int x =1;
cout << x << endl;
return 0;
}

int main ()
{
function1( x);
return 0;
}`  `
```

Comment: Functions in C++ must have a return type. x is not defined in main. lots of other wrong stuff.

Comment: Sounds like you could [use a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: How to use functions will be explained near the start of your book.

Comment: "unless I include it in the main function" I doubt it works even then because your function definition is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this happen?

It happens because `x` is now undefined in the context where you're using it in `main`, and it's *already* defined (as a parameter) in the context where you're trying to define it in `function1()`.

In the first case, you'll definitely get an error because `x` as used in `main` is completely undefined... the compiler is going to look at that `function1(x)` call and wonder what the heck it's supposed to supply for the `x`.

In the latter case, the compiler might let you redefine `x`, but it'll probably at least issue a warning. Also, if it's allowed, then your `function1()` will always print out `1` regardless of what you pass in for the `x` parameter because the newly declared `x` will be used instead of the value passed in the parameter.

The concept that you're missing is called *scope*. Every variable has a *scope*, which is essentially the realm in which it's known. The scope of a variable can be global, in which case it's available to the entire program, or limited to a single file, or it can be declared inside a function or block, in which case it's local to that block of code.

```
int x = 12;   // x is available anywhere in the file and has initial value 12

void foo(int x)
{
    cout << x << endl;    // prints the value passed to foo by the caller
    int x = 34;           // this new x hides the parameter and is available
                          //   anywhere inside this function, but not outside
    cout << x << endl;    // prints the new x, i.e. 34
    {
        cout << x << endl;    // still prints 34
        int x = 97;           // hides the previous x, available only within
                              //   this block or sub-blocks
        cout << x << endl;    // prints 97
    }                         // x from the enclosed block goes out of scope
    cout << x << endl;    // prints 34, because we're back to the x at function scope
}
```

Understanding scope is very important because variable names are often duplicated, either on purpose or by accident, and you need to be able to tell where a given variable is in scope and therefore valid to use, and when it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of C++ coding! Looks like there's more than a few issues in the code here - let's break it down and see what we can find.

First and foremost, to answer your original question, **your declaration of x (in `function1`) was made outside of the function you tried to use the variable in (in `main`).** C++ can't normally see variables you declare in one function when it's running in another; that's by design, and is called [scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope).

To start, the code won't compile for a number of reasons, first and foremost the presence of stray backticks in your code at the very end. These need to be removed.

```cpp
int main ()
{
function1( x);
return 0;
}`  `  //<-- the `  ` will make the compiler angry
```

Now let's have a look at what's causing the error: x isn't yet declared. In C++, a variable has to be "declared" before it can be used. Since "x" hasn't been declared before its use in `function( x);`, the compiler kicks it back since it doesn't know what "x" means. Try this:

```cpp
int x = 0;
function1( x);
```

We're not quite done yet, though. Once we make this change, the compiler will throw another error: `In function 'int function1(int)': 8:5: error: declaration of 'int x' shadows a parameter`. You've already included an int x in the definition of function1; by creating *another* `int x` inside function1, you've steamrolled your original `x`. Let's change that from a definition to an assignment.

```cpp
function1(int x)
{
x =1;
cout << x << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Getting clsoer, but we've got one more error: `6:16: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'function1' with no type [-fpermissive]`. THis is telling you `function1` needs to have a return type, which is a keyword in front of the function's name that tells the compiler what type of data it returns (`void` if it doesn't return any). Looks like you're using `return 0;` - why not return an int?

```cpp
int function1(int x)
```

Now, at last, we've got code that compiles and runs.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



int function1(int x)
{
x =1;
cout << x << endl;
return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    int x = 0;
function1( x);
return 0;
}
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/SuperbConventionalPress)

Good luck!